# Why my factory test raises an error from another factory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, model, devise, factory-bot

I'm quite new with Rspec and factory_bot. I have the following factories:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    email { "test@gmail.com" }
    password { "azerty" }
    username { "test" }
    city { "Paris"}
  end

  factory :game do
    title { "Mega Man X" }
    nostalgia_point { 9 }
    platform { "Super Nintendo" }
    developer { "Capcom" }
    release_date { Date.new(1994,1,1) }
    game_mode { "Single player" }
    genre { ["Adventure", "Platform", "Shooter"] }
    association :owner, factory: :user
  end

  factory :favorite do
    user
    game
  end
end
```

When I run this test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Game, type: :model do
  let!(:favorite) { create(:favorite) }

  describe '::create' do
    context 'persistence' do
      it 'persists the favorite' do
        expect(Favorite.count).to eq(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following error: `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken, Username has already been taken`

I guess it's because my `user` factory (devise model) is not cleaned from my other tests but I'm absolutely not sure... And I don't know if I should use something different from what I did to clean all my database. Here what I wrote in `factory_bot.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers

  config.after :each do
    Warden.test_reset!
  end

  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
end
```

If there is a better practice or just tell me what I'm missing, I'll be very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be a validation in your user model that prevents you from creating users with an email and/or username that's already in the database. And as you have a factory (`favorite`), that attempts to create a user and a game, without checking first if the user email and/or username already exist, it fails because it uses the values you set for them, which are always the same ("test@gmail.com", "test", correspondingly).

You can use a FactoryBot [sequence](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences) for that:

```
sequence :email do |n|
  "test#{n}@gmail.com"
end
sequence :username do |n|
  "test-#{n}"
end
```

That prevents you from using the same value for new records as `sequence` yields an incremental integer, hence the value is guaranteed to not be the same as long as the test suite runs.